# How to find an element in an array by attribute in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help finding an object in an array of jQuery selectors by attribute.

This is the code used for selection of the inputs elements in a table:

```
var tableInputs = $('#clienti-table input:not(#additionalAds)');
```

In variable `tableInputs` there are 13 input elements. I need to find each element by the id attribute.
Is there any way to do it?
Hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want? Do you want an item with a specific id, or do you want a list of the ids? Do you want something else?

Comment: honestly, i think you should be able to find the element you want directly by the id unless you are using duplicated id somewhere else which is not a good practice at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `filter` to get the element with a given id.

```
tableInputs.filter('#'+someid);// this gives you the element in the selection with id `someid`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the colleciton with `.each()`:

```
tableInputs.each(function(){
    var elem = this; //do something with this.
    var id = elem.attr('id');
});
```

Or you can extract an element with a particular id, like this:

```
var $myElem = tableInputs.find('#myId');
```

... or by specifying the context in which to look for your element, like this:

```
var $myElem = $('#myId', tableElements);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < tableInputs.length; i++) {
    console.log(tableInputs[i].id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this... `$('#clienti-table input:not([id='additionalAds']));`

Answer (score 0):

Please try using .find()

```
el = $('#clienti-table input:not(#additionalAds)').find('#id');
```

http://api.jquery.com/find/